# scandir showing wrong results

Tags: php, scandir

My code:

```
if ($d = opendir('.')) {
       while (($file = readdir($d)) !== false) {
            if ( $file != "."  && $file != ".." ){
                echo "filename: $file \n";
                $files[]=$file;
            }
       }
    closedir($d);
}
```

outputs:

> ```
> filename: audio_files
> filename: backup_files
> filename: compressed_files
> filename: database_files
> filename: data_files
> filename: developer_files
> filename: disk_image_files
> filename: executable_files
> filename: font_files
> filename: genstats.php
> filename: raster_image_files
> filename: spreadsheet_files
> filename: text_files
> filename: text_filesdesktop__dup.ini
> filename: video_files
> filename: web_files
> ```

whereas `text_filesdesktop__dup.ini` doesn't even exist.

> ```
> C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Files>del text_filesdesktop__dup.ini
> Could Not Find C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Files\text_filesdesktop__dup.ini
> ```

I have tried using `scandir()`, deleting the file and recreating it, etc, to no avail. I simply can't get that .ini file to go away.

Comment: That PHP code looks too simple to contain a bug. Are you sure you're scanning the right directory? What does `realpath($file)` show? What do you see if you try to get more info about that file (`filesize`/`file_get_contents`)?

Comment: I made a script to move files to their respective folders.. i.e. .txt goes to text_files .mp4 .mpg and so on goes to video_files and apparently desktop.ini got moved because rename() doesn't exclude system/hidden files for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be you are having hidden files in your directory

what platform are your  using  , WiNDOWS OR Linux ,

If you just want to exclude files starting with a dot, ".",

try this:

```
$files = readdir('/path/to/folder');
$files = array_filter($files, create_function('$a','return ($a[0]!=".");'));
```

the above function only returs the files , chich are not starting with .

but on windows hidden files works differently , i dont know how to play with it .